# Why do Power BI and Python display different distributions using Seaborn?

Tags: python, powerbi, seaborn, probability, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset for which I am creating dashboards in Power BI. Since I want to have some violin plots I am using Seaborn, but because Power BI server can't fetch the Python scripts I went back to PyCharm to create the plots there and copy the image into the dashboard.

Bottom line, the two methods generate the same mean, variance, and standard deviations (within an acceptable margin of error) but the two plots have totally different distribution curves. Anyone have any idea why this is happening? I've gone through the data pretty thoroughly to ensure the underlying data is the same and the calculations are the same, and they seem to be, so I am at a loss.

PyCharm plot:

[image: Violinplot from PyCharm]

Power BI plot:

[image: Violinplot from Power BI]

Comment: Well, obviously the underlying dataset is not the same, else you'd get the same output.

Comment: You would think, but they are literally reading from the same file. I checked mean, std, and variance on both datasets and they are identical (within a tenth or hundredth, which shouldn't cause the issue).

Comment: @WmH Would you consider sharing a sample of your dataset as well as the code you've used to produce the plots?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only one thing that could happend is using commas. I really don't know much about your dataset and the BI, but if you have comma's in your dataset (which are used for readability purposes in USA) python can read them other way.

Example: 1.000 - it's one thousand for the USA people (and BI maybe?) but going to python it would be 1. Could that be a case?

Generally, importing the data if you use the same dataset and calculation, is only one possible point of failure.